# How to show 12 hour clock and show the time difference between real time and stored time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm using follwing code to update my Routine. It follows that at certain intervals background changes to specified interval. I would also like to show the Real clock in 12 hour format and also show the Total time left before the next row is highlighted. For example If now row with time interval 11:00-12:00 PM is highlighted then if real time is 11:30 on clock....I would like to show 30 minutes left in side.

Below is my Code

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName, today) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
      tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
      tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    if(typeof today == 'undefined') {
      evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
    else {
      tablinks[today].className += " active";
    }
  }
```

```css
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top:  1px solid black;
    background-color: #808080;
    
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: #808080;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 1px 2%;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
      text-decoration:none;
   text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #810e05;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 2px 2px;
   
    border-top: none;
}

table {

    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% 
    
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;   
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0";
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999; 

 
}

th {
background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    

}

    
th, td {
    
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 16px;

    border-color : black; 
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    
    
}
td{
 color: #060290;  
 
}


tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="animate-in" >
<div style="display: inline;">
<p style="color: red;  font-size: 35px;  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px yellow, 0 0 5px black; display: inline; font-family: my; ">Section </p>
<h1 class="shake-me" style="margin-top: 5px; color: blue;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #999, 0px 2px 0px #888, 0px 3px 0px #777, 0px 4px 0px #666, 0px 5px 0px #555, 0px 6px 0px #444, 0px 7px 0px #333, 0px 8px 7px #001135; text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;'ChunkFiveRegular'; ">A</h1>
               </div>



</div>

  <div class="tab" style="margin-top: 3%;">
  <button class="tablinks"   onclick="openCity(event, 'Sun2')">Sun</button>

  
</div>

<div id="tabcontent" class="selected" >

 
   <!--Sun-->
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
   <table>
   <col width="85%">
  <col width="15%">
    <tr>
      <th>Class</th>
      <th>Time</th>
 
    </tr>
    
       <tr>
      <td id="r1">10:00-12:00PM</td>
      <td ></td>
    
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="r3">12:00-2:00PM</td>
      <td ></td>
     
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="r5">2:00-4:00PM</td>
      <td ></td>
      
       </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="r7">4:00-6:00PM</td>
      <td></td>
     
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td id="r9">6:00-8:00PM</td>
      <td></td>
       </tr>
       
      <td id="r11">8:00-10:00PM</td>
      <td></td>
     <tr> 
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td id="r13">10:00-12:00AM</td>
      <td></td>
      
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td id="r15">12:00-2:00AM</td>
      <td> </td>
      
    </tr>
     <tr>
       <td id="r17">2:00-4:00AM</td>
      <td> </td>
      
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td id="r15">4:00-6:00AM</td>
      <td> </td>
      
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td id="r15">6:00-8:00AM</td>
      <td> </td>
      
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td id="r15">8:00-10:00AM</td>
      <td> </td>
      
    </tr>
   
  </table>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var now = new Date().getHours() * 100 + new Date().getMinutes();
var times = [1000, 1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000, 2200, 2400, 2000, 4000,6000,8000];
var ids = ['r1', 'r3', 'r5', 'r7', 'r9', 'r11', 'r13', 'r15', 'r17'];
var selected = '';
for (var ix = 0; ix < times.length; ix++) {
  if (now >= times[ix]) {
    selected = ids[ix];
  }
}
if (selected) document.getElementById(selected).style.color = " white";
if (selected) document.getElementById(selected).style.fontFamily = '("Futura", cursive, sans-serif)';

if (selected) document.getElementById(selected).style.textShadow = "0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #ff0080, 0 0 30px #ff0080, 0 0 40px #ff0080, 0 0 55px #ff0080, 0 0 75px #ff0080";
if (selected) document.getElementById(selected).style.fontWeight = "2000";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

here I wrote a solution. It works within 24 hours of a day. You can additionally setup it to your needs. There is some comments in code.

```js
            var count_time = [
                { start: { h: 0, m: 0, s: 0 }, end: { h: 2, m: 0, s: 0 } },
                { start: { h: 2, m: 0, s: 0 }, end: { h: 4, m: 0, s: 0 } },
                { start: { h: 4, m: 0, s: 0 }, end: { h: 6, m: 0, s: 0 } },
                { start: { h: 6, m: 0, s: 0 }, end: { h: 8, m: 0, s: 0 } },
                { start: { h: 8, m: 0, s: 0 }, end: { h: 10, m: 0, s: 0 } },
                { start: { h: 10, m: 0, s: 0 }, end: { h: 12, m: 0, s: 0 } },
                { start: { h: 12, m: 13, s: 21 }, end: { h: 14, m: 21, s: 41 } },
                { start: { h: 16, m: 0, s: 0 }, end: { h: 18, m: 0, s: 0 } },
                { start: { h: 18, m: 0, s: 0 }, end: { h: 20, m: 0, s: 0 } },
                { start: { h: 20, m: 0, s: 0 }, end: { h: 22, m: 0, s: 0 } },
                { start: { h: 22, m: 0, s: 0 }, end: { h: 23, m: 59, s: 59 } }                
            ];

            window.setInterval(function () {

                var status = ['elapsed','active','upcoming'];
                var data = '';
                count_time.forEach(function (e) {
                    let i = show_difference(e);
                    // Generate table body
                    data += `<tr class="${status[i['status']]}">
                                <td>${i['start']}&ndash;${i['end']}</td>
                                <td>${i['difference'] !== 0 ? i['difference'] : '&mdash;'}</td>
                             </tr>`;                              
                });
                document.getElementById('my_pretty_table').getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML = data;   

                // Add current time clock
                document.getElementById('current_time').innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', hour12: true });
                
            }, 10);
            function show_difference(time) {

                // Curret time
                var current= new Date();
                var current_ms = current.getTime();
                var current_con = current.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', hour12: true });

                // Start time
                var start = new Date(current.toDateString());
                start.setHours(time.start.h);
                start.setMinutes(time.start.m);
                start.setSeconds(time.start.s);
                var start_ms = start.getTime();
                var start_con = start.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric'/*, second: 'numeric'*/, hour12: true });
                
                // End time
                var end = new Date(current.toDateString());
                end.setHours(time.end.h);
                end.setMinutes(time.end.m);
                end.setSeconds(time.end.s);
                var end_ms = end.getTime();
                var end_con = end.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric'/*, second: 'numeric' */, hour12: true });
                
                // Time left in milliseconds
                var left = end_ms-current_ms;

                // Count millisecons in:
                var day =    1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
                var hour =   1000 * 60 * 60;
                var minute = 1000 * 60;

                // Formating
                var hours = Math.floor((left % day) / hour).toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'decimal', minimumIntegerDigits: '2' });
                var minutes = Math.floor((left % hour) / minute).toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'decimal', minimumIntegerDigits: '2' });
                var seconds = Math.floor(((left % hour) % minute) / 1000).toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'decimal', minimumIntegerDigits: '2' });

                // Time left (formated)
                var difference = left > 0 ? ((hours > 0 ? (hours + ':') : '') + (minutes > 0 ? (minutes + ':') : (hours > 0 ? '00:' : '')) + seconds) : 0;
                // 00:00 (Hours and Minutes) time format (without seconds): 
                // var difference = left > 0 ? ((hours > 0 ? (hours) : '00') + ':' + (minutes > 0 ? (minutes) : '00')) : 0;

                // Time status
                if (current_ms > start_ms && current_ms < end_ms) {
                    var status = 1; // Active
                } else if (current_ms < start_ms && current_ms < end_ms) {
                    var status = 2; // Upcoming
                } else { 
                    var status = 0; // Elapsed
                }
                
                return {
                    start : start_con,
                    end : end_con,
                    status : status,
                    difference : difference
                };
            }
```

```css
 body {
                margin:60px;
            }
            * {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                color: #333;
            }
            #my_pretty_table {
                background: #fafafa;
                border-spacing: 0;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 430px;
                box-shadow: 0 0 12px #eee;
                box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
                border: 10px solid white;
            }
            #my_pretty_table tbody td, #my_pretty_table thead th {
                padding: 13px 17px 13px 17px;
            }
            #my_pretty_table thead th {
                border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
            }
            #my_pretty_table tbody td {
                font-variant-numeric: proportional-nums tabular-nums;
                
            }                
            #my_pretty_table tbody .active {
                background-color: #bbf7b6;
            }

            #my_pretty_table tbody .upcoming {
                background-color:#b6ebf7;
            }
            #my_pretty_table tbody .elapsed {
                color:#ccc;
            }
            #status {
                //background:silver;
                display:flex;
                justify-content:center;
                padding:20px;
            }
            #status > div {
                line-height:30px;
            }
            #a_s, #u_s, #e_s {                
                padding:10px;
            }
            #a_s > div, #u_s > div, #e_s > div {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                margin-right: 5px;
                border-radius: 20px;
                border: 5px solid white;
                box-shadow: 0 0 12px #eee;
                box-shadow: 0 0 4px #bbb;
            }
            #a_s > div  {
                background:#bbf7b6;
            }
            #u_s > div {
                background: #b6ebf7;
            }
            #e_s > div {
                background: #fafafa;
            }
            #current_time {
                
                padding:40px;
                font-size:xx-large;
                text-align:center;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="current_time"></div>
        <table id="my_pretty_table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Time period</th><th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
        <div id="status">
            <div id="a_s"><div>&nbsp;</div>Active</div>
            <div id="u_s"><div>&nbsp;</div>Upcoming</div>
            <div id="e_s"><div>&nbsp;</div>Elapsed</div>
        </div>
        
        </body>
        </html>
```